# how to pass a list as a command line argument to a python script

Tags: python

I have a script - `script.py` where i am parsing a json file(the json file has a list of directories to copy to remote host) and the json parsing returns me 2 lists - list1 and list2.  I am then passing this list1 and list2 to another script `script2` that is called inside `script.py`

Something like

```
#!/usr/bin/python
json = 'jsonfile.json'
input_dir='some path1'
output_dir='some path2'
# function to parse json file and get the lists
# call script2.py
path_to_script2/script2.py list1 list2 input_dir output_dir
```

I tried

e.g., `script2.py list1 list2 input_path output_path`
This says i cannot pass list type to the script

script2.py has

```
import os
import sys
import ast

a = ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1])
b = ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[2])
c = sys.argv[3]
d = sys.argv[4]

print(a)
print(b)
```

when i try this

```
script2.py "list1" "list2" input_path output_path -
```

I am getting this error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/2/script/bexec.p", line 7, in <module>
    a = ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

Here is the json file that i am parsing-

```
{
"list1": ["./xyz1/abc1/file1.sql",
          "./xyz2/abc2/file2.sql",
          "./xyz3/abc3/file3.sql"
          ],

"list2":[
        {"inp": "./xyz03/abc01/file1.txt",
         "csv": ["./xyz03/abc01/file2.csv"],
          "sql": ["./xyz03/file3.sql"],
          "dat": ["./xyz03/Model/file4.dat"],
       },
       { "inp": "./xyz03/abc01/file2.txt",
         "csv": ["./xyz03/abc01/file2.csv"],
         "sql": ["./xyz03/abc01/file3.sql"],
          "dat": ["./xyz03/Model/file4.dat"]}
        ]
}
```

This is just a snippet of the json file- It has more values in `list2` field

Comment: At first you have to pass arguments properly. Arguments that contain spaces or characters that have a syntactical meaning in the shell have to be enclosed in quotation marks.

Comment: Trying to specify JSON data on the command line is just not going to work very well. It's very much not what the command line is designed for. Why not just give names of existing .json files?

Answer (score 1):

`ast.literal_eval()` converts strings in Python literal syntax to the actual objects.  It might be sufficient for what you want:

```
import sys
import ast

a = ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1])
b = ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[2])
c = sys.argv[3]
d = sys.argv[4]

print(type(a),a)
print(type(b),b)
print(c)
print(d)
```

Use case:

```
C:\>script.py [1,2,3,4] {'key1':1,'key2':2} input.txt output.txt
<class 'list'> [1, 2, 3, 4]
<class 'dict'> {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2}
input.txt
output.txt
```

Note if you have spaces in your arguments your shell will required quoting the arguments or escaping the spaces.

```
C:\>script.py [1,2,3,4] "{'key with spaces':1,'key2':2}" input.txt output.txt
<class 'list'> [1, 2, 3, 4]
<class 'dict'> {'key with spaces': 1, 'key2': 2}
input.txt
output.txt
```

Comment: yeah , right. i cannot pass the list as an argument. It throws an error. Quoting did not work. Actually i am passing script.py list1 and list2 input.txt output.txt, where list1 and list2 are returned by a different function in the same script by parsing a json file

Comment: @prex What does "It throws an error. Quoting did not work" mean?  Edit your question with real examples of your use case.  Cut-n-paste actual code that reports an error.